# Parsing issue from WP into iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

OKay I need help here, first off sorry if this might of been answered somewhere else. I just really need to get this done for a client as soon as possible.

Why does the code pull the blog posts and thumbnails from "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/" but not "http://sophisticatedignorance.net/?json=1" ?

Below is code from my iPhone app, it's SUPPOSED to pull blog posts, thumbnails, show who wrote it and the date. If I use the api from the treehouse link like I have below, it works perfect. I replace and use the api from sophisticated ignorance and everything is blank.

Any all help is welcomed.

```
 NSURL *blogurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/"];

NSData *siteData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogurl];

NSError *error = nil;


NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:siteData options:0 error:&error];
self.blogPosts = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *blogPostsArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"posts"];

for (NSDictionary *bpDictionary in blogPostsArray) {
    BlogPost *blogPost = [BlogPost blogPostWithTitle:[bpDictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    blogPost.author = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"author"];
    blogPost.thumbnail = [bpDictionary objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
    blogPost.date = [bpDictionary objectForKeyedSubscript:@"date"];
    [self.blogPosts addObject:blogPost];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the method below to the core.php file on the JSON plugin.

```
public function get_recent_summary() {
    global $json_api;
    $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts();
    $output = array();

    foreach ($posts as $post){
        $post_summary["id"] = $post->id;
        $post_summary["url"] = $post->url;
        $post_summary["title"] = $post->title;
        $post_summary["date"] = $post->date;
        $post_summary["author"] = $post->author->name;
        $post_summary["thumbnail"] = $post->attachments[0]->images["thumbnail"]->url;
        $output[] = $post_summary;

    }

    return $this->posts_result($output);
}
```

From https://gist.github.com/abijlani/5072444.

Then use the URL http://sophisticatedignorance.net/api/get_recent_summary/ instead of http://sophisticatedignorance.net/?json=1